# Add method on model

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I'm using Laravel

Transaction.php model

```
//get user transactions
public static function getTransactions($user_id)
{
    return Transaction::where('user_id', $user_id)->latest()->get();
}
```

I want to add some methods like getClassColore() but I do it this way

```
public static function transaction_color_class($string)
{
    switch ($string) {
        case 'buy':
        case 'withdraw':
            return 'text-danger';

            break;

        case 'charge':
        case 'profit':
        case 'return':
            return 'text-success';
        break;

        default:
            return 'text-muted';
            break;
    }
```

My Question is: is there any way that I can do the following

```
foreach(Transaction::getTransactions(5) as $trans)
{
  echo $trans->getColor();
}
```

**in more OOP Way**

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ultimate OOP way is to use presenters, that are kind of [Decorator Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator/php). Please, read blog post ["Presenters in Laravel"](https://davidhemphill.com/presenters-in-laravel). So, basically you can create a presenter for your model:

```
abstract class Presenter
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array([$this->model, $method], $args);
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->model->{$name};
    }
}

class HtmlPresenter extends Presenter
{
    public function getColor()
    {
        switch ($this->operation) {
            case 'buy':
            case 'withdraw':
                return 'text-danger';
            case 'charge':
            case 'profit':
            case 'return':
                return 'text-success';
            default:
                return 'text-muted';
        }
    }
}
```

Then, asserting you have a collection of your models you can decorate them like the following (using [`mapInto`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods) collection method):

```
$transactions = Transaction::getTransactions(5)
    ->mapInto(HtmlPresenter::class);

foreach($transactions as $transaction) {
    echo $transaction->getColor();
}
```

The author of mentioned blog post even created the [Laravel package](https://github.com/davidhemphill/presenter), that simplifies decoration.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [model accessors and mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor). If your model contains a `type` field for buy, withdraw, charge, etc. then you can do the following:

```
// Transaction.php
protected $classes = [
    'buy' => 'text-danger',
    'withdraw' => 'text-danger',
    'charge' => 'text-success',
    'profit' => 'text-success',
    'return' => 'text-success'
];

public function getClassColorAttribute()
{
    // type would be a column containing buy or withdraw or charge, etc.
    return $this->classes[$this->type] ?? 'text-muted';
}
```

You can access it then like

```
$transaction->class_color
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put your function on the `Transaction` model like so:

```
public function getColor()
{
    switch ($this->deciding_attribute) {
        case 'buy':
        case 'withdraw':
            return 'text-danger';

        case 'charge':
        case 'profit':
        case 'return':
            return 'text-success';

        default:
            return 'text-muted';
}
```

Or you utilize a map for the colors:

```
protected $colors = [
    'buy'      => 'text-danger',
    'withdraw' => 'text-danger',
    'charge'   => 'text-success',
    'profit'   => 'text-success',
    'return'   => 'text-success',
];

public function getColor()
{
    $this->colors[$this->deciding_attribute] ?? 'text-muted';
}
```

Then you can just query your transactions and call the function on them:

```
$transactions = Transaction::where('user_id', $user_id)->latest()->take(5)->get();

foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
    echo $transaction->getColor();
}
```

As a side note, it would make sense to have this logic somewhere in the view/component area though. In my opinion it does not belong on the model.

By the way, I removed the `break;` statements from your `switch-case`, because they are useless in this scenario. If there is a `return` statement before a `break`, the `break` will never be reached anyway.

---

You could also grab the transactions directly from the `User` model to follow even more the OOP approach:

```
class User
{
    // your other model code

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transactions', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function latestTransaction()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Transactions', 'user_id', 'id')
            ->latest();
    }
}
```